# How do I store raw a GeoJson MultiPolygon into MongoDB using Spring Data

Tags: spring-data, geojson, spring-mongodb

How do I easily convert a raw GeoJson MultiPolygon Feature to org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonMultiPolygon so I can save it into MongoDB using SpringData(mongoTemplate)?  I need to keep the holes, of a multipolygon....

GeoJson
https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/978eaa4a10df9467638a5eb9259c84e6

[image]
org.geojson.MultiPolygon to org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonMultiPolygon

Currently the below works and I can save this MultiPolygon to MongoDb.

```
       org.geojson.MultiPolygon multiPolygon ....

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String writer = new StringWriter();
        org.geojson.Feature feature = new org.geojson.Feature();
        feature.setGeometry(multiPolygon);
        mapper.writeValue(writer, feature);                                     
        String geoJson = writer.getBuffer().toString(); 
        Document document = Document.parse( g );                                    
        Object obj = document.get("geometry");
                                
        Place place = new Place();                              
        place.setMultiPolygon(obj);
```

this allows me to do GeoSpatial searching on the multipolygon that contained holes,etc.  i feel this isn't the cleanest way to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i ended up going with is below..there is no way to clearly createa GeoJsonMultiPolygon from a org.geojson.MultiPolygon.

```
  org.geojson.MultiPolygon multiPolygon = //a complicated MultiPolygon with holes,etc.

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String writer = new StringWriter();
        org.geojson.Feature feature = new org.geojson.Feature();
        feature.setGeometry(multiPolygon);
        mapper.writeValue(writer, feature);                                     
        String geoJson = writer.getBuffer().toString(); 
        Document document = Document.parse( g );                                    
        Object obj = document.get("geometry");
                                
        Place place = new Place();                              
        place.setMultiPolygon(obj);
```